# Initializing a string in java error

Tags: java

While running this code on netbeans it always run the if statement block but on compiling it on HackerRank code editor it always go into the else statement . Help me with the error.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Person {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader sb=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int T=sc.nextInt();
    for(int j=0;j<T;j++)
        {String s="";
         s=sb.readLine();
         StringBuffer even=new StringBuffer();
         StringBuffer odd=new StringBuffer();
         if(s!=null)
         {for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
         {
             if(i%2==0)
                 even.append(s.charAt(i));
             else
                 odd.append(s.charAt(i));
         }

        System.out.println(even+" "+odd);
        }
         else
             System.out.println("Enter some input");
        }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using both `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` for input?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using both `scanner` and `bufferedreader`? Try the `next()` method from the scanner instead

```
s=sc.next();
```

If you want to make use of `bufferedreader` then try these two statements instead.

```
int T=Integer.parseInt(sb.readLine());
for(int j=0;j<T;j++)
{
    String s=sb.readLine();
```

Once if you make both the `scanner` and `bufferedreader` listen to input from the inputstream, How will the `bufferedreader` know till where the input has been read? (But the `scanner` knows it)
That's why it returns `null` instead. I hope you understood it.

To keep it simple, just use either the `scanner` or the `bufferedreader` not both.